# Auto run a method of a class

Tags: php, class

When I call my page example.com/do-something, I want my code in `__cunstruct()` to get executed automatically.

```
<?php
class Ajax {
    // POST Manager
    public function __construct() {
        require_once( '../../../wp-load.php' );
        require_once('intern/functions.php');

        $customers = new Customers;

        // Save a comment
        if (isset($_POST['comment']) && $_POST['comment'] === 'save') {
            $this::save_comment();
        }

        // User has been called
        if ($_POST['form_sent'] === 'yes' && (isset($_POST['id']))) {
            $this::mark_user_as_complete();
        }

        // Load a dynamic table for 'closed' customers
        if (isset($_POST['customer_status']) && $_POST['customer_status'] === 'abgeschlossen') {
            $this::get_closed_customers();
        }

        // Load a dynamic table for 'open' customers
        if (isset($_POST['customer_status']) && $_POST['customer_status'] === 'offen') {
            $this::get_open_customers();
        }

        // Mark the user as 'open' and remove him from the 'closed' list
        if ($_POST['customer_uncalled'] === 'yes' && isset($_POST['customer_called_id'])) {
            $this::mark_user_as_open();
        }

        // Show search results
        if (isset($_POST['searchValue']) && !empty($_POST['searchValue'])) {
            $this::show_search_results();
        }
    }
}
```

I thought the `__construct()` would make it but it is not outputting anything. How can I make it run automatically?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you want __construct to run, you need to instantiate the class. I.e. use `new Ajax()` somewhere where you're wanting it.

Comment: Also, why are you using things like `$this::`. You have an instance, but you're calling methods statically. You probably want `$this->` rather than `$this::`, or perhaps `self::`, but it depends on the rest of the class.

Comment: @JonStirling yes I know, but I thought maybe there would be a way, so the __construct would initialize itself.

Comment: In a word. No. __construct won't just randomly run.

Comment: @JonStirling I assumed that but just needed to be sure. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__construct()` will only run if the class has been initialized.

Somewhere in 'do-something.php' you need `$variable_name = new Ajax();` for the constructor to be called.

Comment: If there is no other option to run a method without initializing it, then this answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous class without `$instance = new ...` , with constructor, without name.

Something like this:

```
new class {

  function __construct () {
    header ('Content-Type: text/plain');
    print_r ($_SERVER);
    exit;
  }

};
```

Or like this ..

```
new class {

  function __construct() {
    $this->myPrivateMethodCall();
  }

  private function myPrivateMethodCall () {
    header ('Content-Type: text/plain');
    print_r ('Text from line '. __LINE__ . ' in '. __FUNCTION__ . '() method');
    exit;
  }

};
```

One can also `implement \NS\InterfaceName` and `extend \Real\Class` on anonymous classes.